# Video events of Silverlight player - Google Chrome extension (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, silverlight, events, video, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to track events like stop, play, pause of silverlight online player in google chrome extension? I can get the vidoe element with `document.getElementById("silverlightObject")` but i don't know anything about events of this object. I managed to do it with YouTube- it has `player.getPlayerState()` method. Maybe there is similar way for silverlight player? Anyone can help?

(example) this is website of my interet:
http://www.tvp.pl/vod

this is free video example from this website:
http://www.tvp.pl/vod/seriale/obyczajowe/czas-honoru/sezon-4-odcinki-40-/iv-seria-odc46-znak-rosenfarba/5423075

Answer (score 0):

Unless the author of the Silverlight app explicitly exposes a property or method, I don't know of a way to  probe the state of any `MediaElement` inside it.  There is a way to expose a property in that way, but it sounds like you are using someone else's app without access to their source.

If you do have access to the source of the Silverlight player, you can expose a property using the `ScriptableMember` attribute and `HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject()`, e.g.:

```
//In constructor of view that contains your MediaElement
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("player", this);

...

[ScriptableMember]
public string CurrentState
{
    get
    {
        return this.MediaElement.CurrentState.ToString();
    }
}
```

See [Walkthrough: Calling Managed Code from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more details.